# Error loading native library grpc_csharp_ext x64 dll unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, machine-learning

I'm following the [tutorial in the documentation](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/ml-agents/blob/release_18_docs/docs/Getting-Started.md) of ml-agents from release 18. I'm not able to run the training of the example available. When I try to run the code with anaconda running I get the error `Error loading native library grpc_csharp_ext x64 dll` and the mlagent don't connect to the python code and the agent just runs the heuristic mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was happening because the path to my unity code had special charactes such as ç and other accentuations like ã and á. I saw in a forum that Germans have special characters and when using them in the file names in the path it gave the same error ([see here](https://forum.unity.com/threads/mlagents-library-grpc-issue-in-one-project-but-works-in-another-project-without-any-issues.1131001/)).